# Am I losing information with this printf()?

Tags: c, printf, compiler-warnings

In **Expert C Programming**, there is an exercise on page 146 that is supposed to illustrate how a typical Unix OS allocates various segments of an `a.out` file into various memory segments for execution.

The "starter" code is:

```
main () {
   int i;
   printf("The stack top is near %#X\n", &i);
}
```

The compiler warns, but does not error, the use of `%X` with `&i`:

`warning: format ‘%X’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat]`

As a newcomer to memory layouts and hex addresses, I am just wondering if the recommended formatting is not representing the desired information in full? I searched around but couldn't find anything definitive--for instance, I read about using the `%p` format cue, but it wasn't clear if that was necessary for this case.

Also, it seems doubtful that this sacred C book would make such an error, so I assume it is an extraneous warning for this use case, but I would like to be sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   int i;
   printf("The stack top is near %#X\n", &i);
```

This is undefined behavior. `X` conversion specifier requires an argument of type `unsigned int` but `&i` is of type pointer to `int`. C does not require an implementation to abort translation in case of undefined behavior but an abort of translation is allowed by C.

To print a pointer value use `p` conversion specifier:

```
   int i;
   printf("The stack top is near %p\n", (void *) &i);
```

Comment: @d0rmLife in most compilers you'll get what you expect (the least significant bytes of your address) nevertheless it is an erroneous program.

Comment: Thanks for confirming the use of `%p`. I find it curious that casting to `void*` is necessary.

Comment: @d0rmLife the cast to `void *` is necessary as C requires an argument of type `void *` for `p` conversion specifier.

Comment: An abort of translation is not allowable unless the compiler can prove that the statement that invokes undefined behavior will be executed. That's easy in this particular example, but impossible in general.

Comment: After messing around for a bit, it seems that the print formatting suggested by the author and the updated version you supplied consistently provide the same information. Thought that was interesting! *(I note it is still undefined behavior--but it seems like pretty predictable undefined behavior!)*